# SDCard restore number of sectors

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

I have a 8GB SD card which was pre-loaded with android (included in the hummingboard, a raspberry pi alternative). As I want to flash another OS (OpenELEC), I've inserted this card to my windows PC. The card was detected successfully but reported as 16MB only and so neither windows nor the win32 disk imager was able to format and flash the new image. I've even tried to repartion it using the tool gparted (LiveCD) on a VMWare.

I've tried to format the SD using the tool SD Formatter, but now windows reports it as FAT32 with even less space - 15,9MB. The number of available sectors dropped from 32768 to 32711 (as reported by the VMDK file, that was required for the VMWare).

Do you have any suggestions on how to restore the capacity of the sd card to its complete 8GB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase the MBR (or whatever is installed in the first sector) using the `dd` command:
Boot from a Linux LiveCD, and open a terminal to get a shell prompt.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/xxxx count=16
```

Replace `/dev/xxx` with the proper device name of the SDcard (e.g. `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/mmcblk0`).

Then install a fresh MBR (e.g. using Gparted).

Comment: I tried your command from inside of my VM, but it didn't work - I thought. Now I've inserted the cardand tried to do this again using a LiveCD directly on the PC, but the card already shows as 7.34GB. So I don't know, if you command did the job, or something else. Is this the correct size for a 8GB sd card? I don't have another one for comparision but I would expect it to be more at 7.4-7.5GB.

Comment: *"... but it didn't work"* -- That is not a helpful description.  Useful information is what did happen, rather than what did not happen.  The list of things that did not happen is almost infinite (it didn't blow up, it didn't sing a song etc.), and you only mentioned one.  *"Is this the correct size for a 8GB sd card?"* -- Yes.  Win7 reports an 8GB SDcard of mine as having 7.29 GB capacity.  GParted also reports this same SDcard as 7.29 GB.

Comment: With "_didn't work_" I mean that nothing happend. The command completed successfully, but the card remained as 16MB. But something made the card working again - your command or just some error with the micro SDcard adapter, etc.